# Is it possible to use jQuery in wicked_pdf to render charts?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, highcharts, wicked-pdf

I want to render graphs created by HighCharts, which used jQuery, in the PDF that wicked_pdf generates. I've looked at the [plugin website](http://goo.gl/WnSKT) and it seems like there is a way to do it, I just can't figure it out. My charts work fine in the regular html view. Maybe it's not possible?

Answer (score 1):

I had to adjust the width in the view too, it looked fine in my html view but for some reason the width was very small in the pdf.  Once I set the width in the view and animation to false it worked like a charm.

```
options.chart["width"] = 750,
options.plotOptions["pie"]["animation"] = false
```

Comment: works with pie, can't seem to get it going with line graphs.  Graph shows up but all the lines are thick and grey.

Comment: added the options to my controller and it worked

  `f.options[:plotOptions][:line] = {  
              :animation => false,
              :shadow => false,
              :enableMouseTracking => false
          }`